# Getting the following error "Cannot get a connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object"

Tags: java, oracle, tomcat6, apache-commons-dbcp

Iam getting the below error when iam logging into my application.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot get a connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:82)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:572)
```

Recently we have moved our application from one environment to another environment and yesterday we got the above error. I have researched in internet and everyone is suggesting to check the closing of connections, but i have checked in my code and all the connections were properly closed

Is there any other reason that could cause this issue? Do we have to change the oracle installation parameters in DB? Or any configuration in server.xml would work?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are all the sql.properties and helper files at place?
And the connection properties updated as per the new enviroment.

Comment: are you using any Data Virtualization Layer? it is definately because of open connections but if you are using some DVL layer then it is hard to investigate which all are open.You can also try to check which method is blocking the connection. `Alternaitvely there can be many problems with this much details it is hard to tell what is creating the problem.The possible reasons may be 1) Have you copied the DS files and mentioned the correct DS in code?? 2)Some method might not be auto-committing after it is done??`

Comment: Could you please provide your connection max thread count versus your database max count?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle installation parameters?  No, I don't think so.

It's almost impossible to answer based on what you've posted, so here are a few questions:

1. How have you set up your JNDI connection pool?
2. Is you app under unusually heavy load?  Could the pool be exhausted?
3. Are there any long running threads that are hanging onto connections for too long?

The best way to figure it out is to profile your app.

Comment: We have setup the JNDI connection pool and there there is no much load on application. I will try profiling, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Most likely issue here is that version of underlying DB being used is changed or the jdbc driver being used is outdated.

I have faced such issues while upgrading from 10g to 11g. While upgrading DB , you also need to upgrade oracle driver.

Comment: Hi, the database version is same and iam using ojdbc6.jar. We have got this error only once and afterwards it is working fine.

Comment: The JDBC JAR needs to match your JDK.  The 6 means JDK6.  If you're using JDK7 I'd recommend an upgrade, but that's not your problem.